# SwiftUI tracking "selected" (tapped on) TextField from an outside view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a card view which contains a list of TextFields that are drawn from CoreData, something like:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ForEach(textsArray, id:\.self) { text in
            TextFieldView(textBlock: text, editing: editing)
                .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                    selected.selectedText = text
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The textfield stores its contents and color in CoreData.

This card is displayed by an Edit view. The edit view also contains a ColorPicker, which should allow you to modify the color of the selected text field. So, if the user taps on a text field and starts editing it, a color picker will appear in the corner of their screen to allow them to modify the color of that field.

I attempted to create an observable object to keep track of the selected text field:

```
class Selection:ObservableObject {
@Published var selectedText : TextBlock?
}
```

Then my edit view would simply keep track of the selected text:

```
@ObservedObject var selected : Selection = Selection()
```

It also passes it down into the card view.

The issue is that the ColorPicker view requires a binding to a CGColor. I'm not sure how to pass this binding to the ColorPicker: I tried this:

```
ColorPicker("", selection: self.selected.selectedText.$color)
```

But XCode tells me there's no member of selected text called $color, which I guess is because color is @NSManaged rather than a @State property.

How can I pass a binding of the Color property to the color picker? Am I even approaching this the right way? I'm brand new to iOS development so I have no idea what the idiomatic ways of doing things are.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, it will help understanding the relationships between the views and models

Comment: You could use `@EnvironmentObject` to be notified from all views

Comment: Why don't you just bind the managed object to a property in your edit view and then when the user changes the colour, you update the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate it into other view and call like

```
if self.selected.selectedText != nil {
    MyColorPicker(selection: self.selected.selectedText!)
}
```

where

```
struct MyColorPicker: View {
  @ObservedObject var selection: TextBlock

  var body: some View {
    ColorPicker("", selection: self.$selection.color)
  }
}
```